# WordPress - Mobile Stacking Order of ShortCode Columns

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

This is incredibly simple yet driving me bonkers!

I'm working on a Wordpress theme and using the plugin Shortcodes Ultimate which bases its styling on the Bootstrap library. I am a beginner when it comes to Bootstrap and needed some help rearranging elements on a mobile/tablet device (<770px).

Basically what I'm looking to do is have the `<h2>` and `<p>` on the left side of the screen on a desktop version and the `<img>` on the right (which they are already).

When the viewport width is <770px I would like to have the `<img>` on top of the `<h2>` and `<p>`. But what currently happens is the opposite of this :(

```
[div]
    [div]
      <h2>Our Roots</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
    [/div]
    [div]
      <img src="some-image.png">
    [/div]
[/div]
```

Comment: the push and pull classes built in to bootstrap would work, why don't you look at the docs?

Answer (score 0):

Move the img div higher and use pull-right to float it to the right side for desktop views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Media calls and create custom CSS for each of your situations and use the pull-left and pull-right classes for you first situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the responses, still learning bootstrap. What I did was this and it worked perfectly:

```
[div]
    [div]
      <img src="some-image.png" class="mobile">
      <h2>Our Roots</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
    [/div]
    [div]
      <img src="some-image.png" class="desktop">
    [/div]
[/div]
```

I basically just placed the image twice and applied this CSS:

```
.mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width 770px) {
  .mobile {
    display: block;
   }
  .desktop {
    display: none;
   }
}
```

Still learning :)